# Training ImageNet on Resnet - Dropping LR has little improvement on accuracy

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, object-recognition, residual-networks, image-net

I'm trying to train Resnet50 on Imagenet following [this paper [1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02677.pdf) as well as [this one[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf).

They say that at approximately every 30 epochs, I should drop the learning rate by 10.
Since I'm training on 8 GPUs, I adjusted the learning rate according to [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02677.pdf).

$$ \text{Original  } \eta = 0.1 $$
$$ \text{Original  Batch} = 256 $$
$$ \text{Per-GPU } \eta = 0.025$$
$$ \text{Per-GPU Batch}  = 64$$

The problem I have is that when I divide the learning rate by 10 (at convergence $\approx$ 30 epochs), I don't get as much improvement as [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02677.pdf) and [[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf).

[image]

Has anyone else had this issue? Any advice?

Thanks,

Liam